# Overwrite tpl-footer.php in child

Tags: parent-theme

I am trying to overwrite a template file (tpl-footer.php) in my child-theme.
According to the wordpress docs this should be possible just by adding the file with the same name and the same path into the child-theme. When I do so, nothing happens.

The theme I use is **snsnitan**

Does anyone know what I am missing?
Do I need to overwrite more files?

The footer.php in parent theme has just:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: [Is this your theme?](https://themeforest.net/item/nitan-fashion-woocommerce-wordpress-theme/16936963) Generally speaking: it should work by just having the same filename in the child theme. But it can differ from how the theme authors have implemented loading the file. So your best bet for a proper answer is to ask them.

Comment: yes it is. They provided a child theme package ready to use and they refer to the wordpress docs how to use this child theme.

Comment: If the file is loaded via `get_template_part` then yes, but if it's included using `include`/`require` then it can't. Your theme vendor will know the answer

Comment: ok thank you @TomJNowell. if its using include/require, is there any option to overwrite it anyway and use parents functions?

Comment: If it's using `include`/`require` then your options are extremely limited, and no generic solution will exist as `require` and `include` are not WordPress functions that you can override, they're PHP language features. Your only options then would be help from the theme author, or a hard fork of the theme. Your theme vendor may provide a method to do this, but only they can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the file is included via `get_template_part` or a part of the template hierarchy, then yes**, create a file with the same name in a child theme and WordPress will preferentially load that file.

**If the file is included via `include`/`require`, then no**, those are PHP language features, not WordPress functions, there is no way to intercept or override them so that your file is loaded instead. Either fork the theme or contact the theme support route. The author may have provided alternative methods of overriding the template, or be able to add support for it.

Remember, child themes let you preferentially load child theme templates via the template hierarchy and `get_template_part`. They can't auto-replace arbitrary PHP files, CSS, JS etc files by putting them in a child theme and expecting them to be used instead

Comment: thanks again for this explanation.